# Return error at ajax call in mozila

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jasper server and rails app . From rails app I calling ajax request for logout the jasper report session. And both app deployed using **ngnix** server.

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/jasperserver-pro/logout.html?showPasswordChange=null',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {},
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data)
      },
       error: function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

           }
    });
```

Return XHR.status =0. 
It's work in chrome but not work in mozila.

Comment: It's a blind guess, but is it possible that it's related to the fact it's cross-domain? I've found this article https://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/954551 that implies the crossDomain attribute is not meant for Firefox.

Comment: Is there another way?